# Multiple time frame moving average showing consistent colors

Tags: colors, pine-script

The goal is to have different time frames of the same MA period colored based on the criteria below. Exmaple i want the MA from the 5min chart to be plotted with the proper colors regardless of what happens

problem is the script splits up a higher time frame into my current one. 5min is split into five 1min bars. these 1min bars' colors do not correlate with the 5min TF color when plotted. See the picture attached, the circled squares are in regular intervals but there are grey squares in between that i want to either color green or ideally get rid of. im on a 1 min time frame and the circles are of the 5min TF [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vDxq.png)

here is the code for the 1min, the higher TFs replace '1' with '5' where needed.

```
//overlay is false
timeframe1          = input(1, "Timeframe 1", minval=1)

calculateBg(timeframe) =>
    sma = security(syminfo.tickerid, tostring(timeframe), sma(close, 20))
    uptrend = sma > sma[1] and close > sma
    downtrend =   sma < sma[1] and close < sma
    downtrend ? color.red : uptrend ? color.green : color.new(#B2B5BE, 50)

plotshape(1.00, "1", shape.square, location.absolute, color=calculateBg(timeframe1), size=size.tiny, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations must be done in `security()`'s HTF context. Default HTF TF was changed to 5min:

```
//@version=4
study("")
timeframe1          = input(5, "Timeframe 1", minval=1)

calculateBg(timeframe) =>
    sma = sma(close, 20)
    uptrend = sma > sma[1] and close > sma
    downtrend =   sma < sma[1] and close < sma
    [up, dn] = security(syminfo.tickerid, tostring(timeframe), [uptrend, downtrend])
    dn ? color.red : up ? color.green : color.new(#B2B5BE, 50)

plotshape(1.00, "1", shape.square, location.absolute, color=calculateBg(timeframe1), size=size.tiny, transp=0)
```

Comment: Flawless. Thank you!